# paperjs draw a point with a specified length

Tags: paperjs

Im trying to draw a point with specified length but don't see any output.

http://jsfiddle.net/hLzdj1r2/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" class="canvas-mouse-tracker"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    paper.install(window)
    paper.setup('myCanvas')

   var myPath = new Path();
   myPath.strokeColor = 'black';
   p = new Point(100,100)
   p.length=400
   /* p1 = new Point(500,500) */
   myPath.add(p);
   //myPath.add(p1);

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You may display a point using Path.Circle class

See sample http://jsfiddle.net/hxk2wmrf/

```
   radius = 5;
   p = new Path.Circle(new Point(100,100), radius)
   p.fillColor='red';
```

Path.Circle reference http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#path-circle-center-radius

Answer (score 0):

Points don't have a length. They are just [points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(geometry)) which describe a *location* on a plane/view. Your issue seems to stem from a slight misunderstanding on what a geometric point is, not from PaperJS.

> Geometric points do not have any length, area, volume or any other dimensional attribute.

A `Path` on the other hand does have a `length`, but that is determined by it's `segments`, which connect the points you specify.

Here's an example, where I create a `Path` that connects 3 points.

```js
paper.setup(document.querySelector('canvas'))

let path = new paper.Path({
  strokeColor: 'black',
  segments: [
    new paper.Point(50, 50),
    new paper.Point(100, 50),
    new paper.Point(100, 100)
  ]
})

console.log(path.length)
```

```css
canvas[resize] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.11.5/paper-core.min.js"></script>

<canvas resize></canvas>
```